# Can I repeat the question in different communities in Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I have posted n question in **Unix&Linux** community. Can I also put the question in **Stack Overflow** community in order to get more answers from more people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off: ***verbatim cross posting is frowned upon***

1. Tailor your question to your audience:
   A SO question has certain [quality standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and requirements it needs to fulfil. These may be different from the ones over at Unix & Linux (or wherever else). Also people expect different things from a question to be considered good.
2. Investing into your question:
   Some people just have a dislike for cross-posted questions. I am one of them. Cross-posted questions are... problematic. If you as OP recieve an answer on one site, you <s>maybe</s> probably stop investing the effort it would need on the other side. Maybe (if you feel happy) you post a self-answer with the solution found on another site, but odds are you just leave it there, rotting :(
3. Duplication of information:
   A duplicate question may inadevertently duplicate a lot of information in answers. This is especially true for problem-solving questions like: "Why does my program fail when ..."
   This is unecessary and bluntly speaking ... dumb.

#### But, sometimes

Questions can be tailored to their respective communities. Example: You ask a question about security of your code concerning user-storage. This may be a well-recieved question on both [Code Review](http://codereview.stackechange.com) and [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com). Keep in mind, you should tailor your question to your audience and be prepared to invest time in both questions.